# A ring with 2 minimal left ideal and 3 minimal right ideal

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there a (finite) ring with exactly 2 minimal left ideal and exactly 3 minimal right ideal? (rings are assumed to have identity)

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ be the set of all $3\times 2$ matrices over a field $F_2$ with usual addition. Let $P$ be  the $2\times 3$ matrix consisting of $1$'s. Define a multiplication: $A*B= APB$. Then we get a ring (this is so-called Munn algebra) with required properties (a minimal left ideal is generated by a column).

In such a way you can obtain a ring with $m$ minimal left ideals and $n$ minimal right ideals.

**Addendum** (Thanks to Manny Reyes) $M$ doesn't contain an identity element, but we can join an identity $e$ to $M$, i.e. consider the ring $M_1$ of pairs $(a,me)$ ($a\in M, m\in F_2$) with multiplication $(a,me)*(b,ne)=(a*b+na+mb,mne)$. Then minimal ideals of $M_1$ are the same of $M$.

Comment: This is a very clever idea, but this ring doesn't seem to have an identity element.  Such an element $X \in M$ would need to be a $3 \times 2$ matrix satisfying $PX = I_2$ and $XP = I_3$.  The latter is impossible by rank considerations.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Manny Reyes: Thank you very much, I forgot about the identity. I will correct the answer.

Comment: +1 Nice. What can you tell about the form of maximal (left or right) and prime ideals of $M$ (or $M_1$)?

Comment: @Silvi: There is an analogy with usual matrix rings over a field: if we consider a minimal left ideal as the additive group, it is the direct sum of the additive groups of the field.

Comment: So what are the maximal left ideals of $M$?

Comment: @Silvi: Sorry, I had read your first question wrong mean "minimal" instead "maximal". A maximal ideal is a direct sum of all minimal ideals without one of them.

Comment: Thanks. How about prime ideals? Any characterization for them? By the way do you know any references concerning Munn algebra's  I and their ideal structure, they seems to be very interesting.

Comment: @Silvi: I don't interested by prime ideals, but I think it is not a difficult problem. As to references, see Okniński, J. Semigroup Algebras. New York: Dekker, 1991.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the ring $R = \Bbb{Z}_2<a,b \; | \; a^3 = b^2 = ba = a^2b = 0>$ ($a,b$ are non-commuting indeterminate). Then every element of $R$ is a linear combination of $1,a,b,a^2,ab$. Therefore $|R| = 32$, also $R$ is a local ring and satisfies the asked conditions.